# How do divs indent inside a div

Tags: html

I am looking for an explanation for the following behavior.
I have two `display:inline-block` divs (`#secondlevel1` and `#secondlevel2`) inside a parent div `#firstlevel`. I do not understand why the first div (`#secondlevel1`) is aligned to the bottom margin of the parent div and the `#secondlevel2` div is aligned to the top margin of the parent div. I did not specify any alignment, so I did not expect this to happen. Can someone enlighten me? I want to know exactly how the indentation default rules work.

I want to keep both `#secondlevel2` and `#secondlevel1` divs aligned to the top margin of the parent and let the `#secondlevel1` div expand vertically as the rows of the table of the first div increase. Is there a way to do that? I don't prefer using floats if I could help.

I also have it entered on http://jsfiddle.net/Ljazf/2/ for easy viewing.

```
</div>

    <div style="display:inline-block" id="firstlevel">
        <div style="display:inline-block;padding:10px;width:200" id="secondlevel1">
            <div  id="distance" style="">
                Distance from Agra to Ajmer
            </div>
            <input style="width:inherit" type="text">
            </input>
            <table style="width:inherit">
                <tr>
                    <td>asdf</td>
                    <td>aaaa</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>asddd</td>
                    <td>asff</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div id="secondlevel2" style="width:;height:100;display:inline-block">
            <input  style="display:block" type="text">
            </input>

            <input  style="display:block" type="text">
            </input>
            <button style="display:block" value="hello">
            Hehehhe</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: There was another answer which I can't see now which I wanted to accept. I also have been penalized in reputation and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add vertical-align:top; to your first div

Comment: Your solution works but I am not merely looking for a solution. I am looking for an explanation for the above behavior.